# Cannot play audio file through java

Tags: java

In my program I am trying to play an audio file of a women screaming. I am using a simple code, through sun.audio, but am unable to get the file to play. 
Here is the code:

```
package hauntedHouseAdventure;

import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;

public class AudioScreamer {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception {`

        // open the sound file as a Java input stream
        String screamFile = " C:/Users//alan/Downloads/woman-scream-01.au";
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(screamFile);

        // create an audiostream from the inputstream
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

        // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:  C:\Users\alan\Downloads\woman-scream-01.au (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hauntedHouseAdventure.AudioScreamer.main(AudioScreamer.java:19)
```

Comment: I would have thought that the exception was reasonably obvious...the file doesn't exist.  Try adding `System.out.println("Exists: " + new File().exists("C:/Users/alan/Downloads/woman-scream-01.au));` before you try and load the file. You want it to say `true`. Also note that you have a leading space in you path name `" C:/"`, not sure if that will have an effect or not...

Comment: And it was the space. Now I feel all silly. What tripped me up, was that there was a previous error that stated file does not exist. I thought this was a different error. Thank you for the help MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 3):

Just so we can close this question...

Try using `File` and checking to see if the file actually exists...

```
String screamFile = " C:/Users/alan/Downloads/woman-scream-01.au";
File fileOfScream = new File(screamFile);
System.out.println("Exists: " + fileOfScream.exists());
```

You want it to print `true`.

Also, your path has a leading space...

```
" C:/Users/alan/Downloads/woman-scream-01.au";
 ^------
```

Which may cause it to not find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java application returns a file not found exception because you have put a space between " and C:/".
Remove the space and it works as expected.